# Where to find what queries are hitting to gremlin server via gremlin-javascript

Tags: node.js, titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am using gremlin-javascript module of nodejs to query titan database. Everything is working fine but I want to monitor what is actually hitting the gremlin server and anything else that i can get to know about that query. I already checked the gremlin-server log in logs folder inside the titan folder . I can not find anything of use in those logs. Any help in this regard will be extremely useful. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a client side solution with gremlin-javascript, there is currently no quick and easy way to log to the console outgoing queries or protocol messages sent to Gremlin Server.

You could either:

1. Implement your own function that wraps calls to the Gremlin client methods you call (typically `client.execute()`), and logs arguments. If using Node.js v6+, this could be a nice use case for an ES2015 `Proxy` object. This is the safest, non intrusive approach.
2. Monkeypatch the `client.prototype.messageStream` method, and log parameters. As of v2.3.2, this low level method gets called whether you're doing `client.execute()` or `client.stream()`. This is riskier and trickier.
3. Quick and dirty: edit the source code in `./node_modules/gremlin/lib/GremlinClient.js` and add this after line 405 (`prototype.messageStream` definition):

   ```
   console.log('query:', script);
   console.log('params:', bindings);
   ```

There's currently an [open issue about logging of ingoing messages](https://github.com/jbmusso/gremlin-javascript/issues/20) but this could be developed to include outgoing messages as well (queries with parameters, down to protocol messages).

Comment: thanks again jbmusso, opting the quick and dirty one for faster prototyping .